# Вызвано исключение в c++

Tags: c++, стек

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

//Функция заполнения массива
void fill_array(char arr[13], const char *info = "fill_array\n") {
    std::cout << info;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) arr[i] = info[i];
}

int main()
{
    char info[] = "dong!";
    std::cout << info << std::endl;
    fill_array(info);
    std::cout << info << std::endl;
}
```

Этот код вызывает ошибку:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the   variable 'info' was corrupted.

Почему оно переполняет стек?

Comment: просто потому что  размер  info  не хватает для того, чтоб вы туда пихнули второй аргумент функции< 13 символов

Answer (score 3):

```
char info[] = "dong!";
```

info - это массив из 6 элементов.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) arr[i] = info[i];
```

Вы же пытаетесь переписать 13 элементов, в результате чего выходите за пределы массива и портите данные в стеке.

Comment: тоесть надо зделать эго динамическим,верно?

Comment: @fvBn: Надо чтобы код не вылезал за пределы массива. А "динамический" он или нет не имеет никакого значения - это дело десятое.

Answer (score 0):

```
//#include "stdafx.h" Закомментировал, поскольку мне оно не требуется - использую GNU/Linux
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // Требуется для strlen. По факту, C-строки лучше не использовать. Вместо них - std::string из заголовочного файла `string`

void fill_array(char* arr, const char *info = "fill_array\n") {
  // Функция заполнения массива
  std::cout << info;
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(info); i++)
    arr[i] = info[i];
}

int main() {
  char info[13] = "dong!"; // Компилятор выделяет под этот массив 6 байт - под `dong!` и под терминальный символ '\0'. Этого не хватает, что-бы скопировать туда строку из 13 байт.
  std::cout << info << std::endl;
  fill_array(info);
  std::cout << info << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы наткнулись на подводный камень с передачей массива в функцию. Дело в том, что в этом случае тип аргумента функции деградирует до `char *` **полностью игнорируя** указанный размер массива. Реально функция выглядит вот так:

```
void fill_array(char * arr, const char *info = "fill_array\n") {
   std::cout << info;
   for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) arr[i] = info[i];
}
```

Ну а передавая в нее `char info[]` (имеющий размер 6 байт) вы прямо осуществляете переполнение.

Выводов можно сделать два:

- в сигнатуре функций никогда не должно быть массивов;
- при передаче в функцию указателя на данные для записи всегда должен передаваться размер буфера, на который он указывает;

Comment: тогда я выделю под нее 13 байт:    char info[13]    или зделаю динамичесим масивом:char *info = new char[6];

Comment: @fvBn: `char info[13]` поможет. А вот почему вы хотите сделать `char *info = new char[6];` - не ясно. Каким это образом вам поможет, если вы все равно будете писать 13 символов в массив размера 6?